# What is my SP farm name (NOT SP farm account name)?

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, farm

Currently using SP2013, I only found tutorials that show the name of farm **account** only. Is there any way to get the farm name itself? Powershell, cmd, settings, etc...? Please help me thanks!

Comment: what you mean by farm name? or what are your expectation about name?

Comment: To get farm name, we can use "(Get-SPFarm).Name" powershell script to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

In Powershell

Use `(Get-SPFarm).DefaultServiceAccount.Name` should give you the Farm Account

Comment: I need the farm name, not the farm account name. Thks.

Answer (score 1):

Farms do not have names. They have unique IDs, e.g. `(Get-SPFarm).Id`.

Answer (score 1):

For Powershell you also have:

```
$SPFarm = Get-spfarm
$SPFarm.ID
```

Or in SharePoint 2013 Management Shell paste this:

```
(Get-SPFarm).Id
```